# How to crawl image link - Python & beautifulsoup

Tags: python, image, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am currently crawling a web page (https://www.getyourguide.de/s/?q=tokio&customerSearch=1&searchSource=2) using Python 3.7 and bs4 in order to collect the images of the respective activities.

I found that the links are located in the html source like this:

```
<div class="activity-card-image container">                                                                                                         
<img class="" data-src="https://cdn.getyourguide.com/img/tour_img-1621839-68.jpg" data-role="cover" alt="tokio skytreeticket" src="https://cdn.getyourguide.com/img/tour_img-1621839-68.jpg">
```

But after several trials, this "https://cdn.getyourguide.com/img/tour_img-1621839-68.jpg" never show up.

Here is my logic so far:

```
for reg in RegionIDArray:
    r = requests.get("https://www.getyourguide.de/-l" +str(reg) +"/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")


    g_data3 = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "activity-card-image-container"})
    for item in g_data3:
        print(item.get("scr"))
```

Output:

```
  None
  None
  None
  None
```

Could you guys help me put? Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: check if `scr` is just a typo in your code here but maybe also in your project. `src` maybe works

Comment: page is dynamic. those are not present in the static html source code.

Comment: You'll have to use Selenium to let the page render first. Then you can pull the the html and use your code